# Regex appears to return pos >1 but length 0

Tags: regex, coldfusion

The following code is returning an error on Mid, saying the third argument is -2 - so it thinks the length is 0. We're totally stumped as to how this could happen. The code looks for values between curly braces and strips them out. Can you think of a way to break this?
Str can be anything - we don't know, it's not supplied by us - so that's the var you want to break.

```
str = "Here's a string with {EmailAddy} and maybe some {otherVariables}";
start = 1;
pos = 0;
length = 0;
tokens = ArrayNew(1);
while(true) {
    x = REFind("\{\w*\}", str, start, true);
    pos = x.pos[1];
    length = x.len[1];

    if (pos == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        // get the token, trimming the curly brackets
        token = mid(str, pos+1, length-2);  
        arrayAppend(tokens, token);
        start = pos + length;
    }
}
WriteDump(tokens);
```

Comment: [rematch](http://cfdocs.org/rematch)?

Comment: CF doesn't support lookbehind, so REMatch will get me the matches including the curly braces. Be a lot prettier if we could do it that way though!

Also, not looking to rewrite so much as to break. We're mostly curious about how the heck we got an error on this in the first place.

Comment: I ran this code in CF10, and it ran fine with no errors.  Where did you see the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need lookbehind:

```
var Tokens = rematch( "\{\w*(?=\})" , Arguments.Str );

for ( var i = 1 ; i LTE ArrayLen(Tokens) ; i++ )
    Tokens[i] = Tokens[i].substring(1);

return Tokens;
```

And that code should also give you a clue as to the most likely cause of the code breaking, in that you've probably got it in a function in a persisted component, but (without any scoping) everything is going in the component's variables scope, and thus it's not thread-safe and - with multiple calls under load - the variables involved are liable to get corrupted.

This is a general issue you should be looking for throughout the code - generally the first assignment for every variable inside a function should be prefixed with either the `var` keyword (or explicitly the `local.` scope) to ensure it it local to that function and not global the the component. (Except of course in the instances when a global variable is what is desired.)

---

Oh, and if you ever do actually want/need to use lookbehind in CF, I've made [cfRegex](http://cfregex.net/), a library that wraps Java's more powerful regex engine, providing support for lookbehind (with limited-width), and with a (hopefully) easy to use and consistent set of functions for interacting with it.

Comment: You are exactly right, sir: it was an unvar'd var, which I should have noticed immediately. And your code there is slicker than my code; nice substring.

Also, hey, you're the cfRegex guy. I checked that out. Great work.

Comment: Just realized that my "your code is slicker" comment was probably confusing. I'd already re-written this chunk:
`var tokens = REMatch("\{\w*\}", str);  
var i = 0;  
     
for (i = 1; i <= arrayLen(tokens); i++) {  
     tokens[i] = replace(tokens[i], "{", "");  
     tokens[i] = trim(replace(tokens[i], "}", ""));  
}`  

As you can see, it's pretty close to what you suggest, but not quite as good.